# How do i wrap a parent div to the width of a child div (dialog)?

Tags: css, angularjs, single-page-application

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/2/) to demonstrate my issue.

I have a SPA (Single Page Application).
In the appliation several dialogs can popup on the screen.
Every popup has it own width and height.

The title and content of the dialogs are added by angularJs
The problem i have here is the size of the dialog.

Currently all popups are made and added seperatly. I want to change this into one popup with variable content. The problem that comes with this is that the popup must wrap the contents width.

Example (as shown in the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/2/))

```
<div class="dialog">
    <div class="titlebar"></div>
    <div class="content">
       The content that is added has css that tells it has a width of 400px
       This means the dialog needs to wrap to this 400px
    </div>
</div>
```

**How do i solve this by only using CSS?**

---

Some examples of the variation of popups (although the width of both look the same, this is not the case)

[image: Popup 1]
[image: Popup 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For young browser you may use :

---

**1)** `display:flex;` property (includes centering) **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/15/)**

```
.backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
.backdrop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.dialog {
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

---

**2)** `max-content` as value for `width` and not set any width to inner
    content . (exept some padding to keep room for the close button) :
    **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/7/)**

Info on [W3C about those new keywords value](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/#width-height-keywords), soon avalaible i hope.

CSS updated

```
.dialog {
    width: max-content;
    z-index: 101;
    margin: auto;
    /* basic way t o center */
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-80px -150px;

}

.titlebar {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;    
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.title{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: x-large;
    padding:0 50px 0 10px;
}

.close_button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffd549;
    color: #000000;
}

.content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.content-width {
    background-color:#FFF000;
}
```

or as already said , use the `display:` [`table`](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/8/), [`inline-table`](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/9/)

Comment: The `margin: -80px -150px;` is not acceptable as the contents width is not known

Comment: @Marcel thanks for your comment and feedback. **This was not the question** and it stands here for the demo purpose, if centering needs to be fixed in case you follow the max-content hint, just ask for it :)

Comment: The new added answer is exactly what i'm looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Use `display:table` for the dialog.

Here is your [Updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/10/)

Comment: That's the proper answer IMHO

Comment: looks promising, but I want the popup in the middle of the screen.

Comment: You can achieve that using jquery. see the updated link.

Comment: This is a correct answer, only not with CSS only. (p.s. i deleted the `margin:auto;` to get the result i want. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: inline-block; text-align: center;`

Works in [ie >= 8](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/4/).

Answer (score 1):

A div without a set width will take up the width of the parent.

try this.

```
.content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.content-width {
width: 100%;
background-color:#FFF000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/6/

Checking again now. You can just remove the width from those two classes and it will work.

This is what you want I think.

http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/16/

Comment: This still does not center the popup, or am I wrong?

Comment: it is centered but will grow with the screen as it expands.

Comment: removing the comment from the width of .dialog does center it.

Comment: Ahh yes that does the trick. Only the width there was to show wat i wanted to achieve. In the SPA the width is provided in the content. The .dialog needs to be a container that wraps the contents WIDTH, not to being set to a WIDTH.

Comment: I've read up and tried to fix yours but I do not think you can center elements that are position: fixed;

this is the closest I got http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/13/

Comment: You are close! [This](http://jsfiddle.net/VQA4k/11/) is the result i'm looking for without the javascript. I found this article about unknown width by centering. Mayby this is what i'm looking for [Centering in the unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

Comment: Nice one. But as soon as you position that element you will face issues again I think. As it is there it won't display over your page (As a popup)

Comment: Thats correct, it's a fixed popup! but it will display in front of all other content. But thats the behavior i'm looking for! Now only without the js :)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use javascript? If you don't want to use jQuery you can still accomplish this with native javascript without any libraries.

Comment: yes, because this is typically an issue that should (and can) be solved with only css. This way I only have to worry about the content to be added and not about if the dialog is scaled and positioned right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the problem.
If you want to center the content-width div element, simply add `margin: auto;`.
If you want the container to fit the WIDTH of its content, you must change the `display` property from `block` to something else, like `inline-block` or `table` (as suggested by @jacelysh).

What is it exactly that you are trying to do?

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear enough, To clearify: The popup (container) needs to be centered on the page and wrap the content provided. i.e. the content has a div with a WIDTH of 400px, The popup (container) needs to wrap this to the center of the screen (and provide a title message and a close button)